# Unable to delete object in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to delete an object with a specific value from an array and all code and syntax seems abortive even with the ones I copied on this platform.

```
// UNABLE TO WRITE "DELETE" CAMPUS DIRECTOR CODE
router.delete("/:id/director", userAuth, checkRole(["admin"]), async(req, res) => {
    const campus = await Campus.findById(req.params.id);
    const campusAdmins = campus.admins
    // campusAdmin will return a single object in an array [{_id: 1234567865434543, title: "campus director", userId: "9876543456fdfgfdgf"}]
    try {
        campusAdmins.splice(campusAdmins.findIndex(e => e.title === "campus director"),1);
        console.log(campusAdmins);
        res.status(201).json("You've successfully delete campus director");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
```

help me solve this problem pls.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `campusAdmins` returns the object you've specified in the comment?

There is no issue with the syntax, this works:

```js
const campusAdmins = [{
  _id: 1234567865434543,
  title: "campus director",
  userId: "9876543456fdfgfdgf"
}];

try {
  campusAdmins.splice(campusAdmins.findIndex(e => e.title === "campus director"), 1);
  console.log(campusAdmins);
  console.log("Successfully deleted campus director");
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Failure");
}
```

Comment: It actually shows that the object is deleted, but the object is still in the database.

Comment: Thanks boss, i finally solved it, i forgot to add campus.save() to my code